# how to stop redirection for sub-domain using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

my website have two different version
one is for desktop and second one is for mobile.
therefore in .htaccess file i have put below code that if someone enter my website from mobile so he/she will redirect to mobile version which is like that
**m.example.com** but

My problem is i also have one sub-domain. and when someone try to go on my sub-domain which is like this blog.example.com so my .htaccess is checking if he trying to reach my sub-domain from mobile so he is redirecting him to my mobile version. And this is i do not want. i want that redirection code will work just for my front domain not for sub-domain.

please help someone.

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com [R,L]

#redirect mobile ends here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
```

This checks to redirect only if not already on subdomain m. You could add a rule exactly like it to block blog too.

```
# Check if we're trying to reach the blog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^blog\.
```